# Electron bands in solids and delocalized electrons

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

Most introductory textbooks introduce electron bands when discussing metal properties which gives the impression that electron bands are strictly affiliated with delocalized electrons.

However, bands are also discussed in the context of covalent solids as well as ionic solids, where electrons are local to a bond or to an atom. How is it possible for a band to form of localized electrons? Are band in this case an abstract concept?

My understanding tis that bands form when the electron orbitals start to overlap. If the electrons are localized then doesn't that mean there is no overlapping and thus no bands?

Comment: Bands are an abstract concept and applicable whenever you have periodicity of some sort. If the orbitals are not very much overlapping, i.e. pretty much localised, then the band will be extremely flat, i.e. the energy eigenvalues will be pretty much constant and independent of the wavevector $k$. Only when they overlap and interact a lot do you have bands that span a wide range of energies.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent When you say flat, does it mean that the width of the band approaches zero? As in it becomes more of an orbital rather than a band of large number of very closely spaced levels?

Comment: No, I mean that the "band of a large number of very closely spaced levels" becomes so closely spaced energy levels that they are exactly the same energy eigenvalue. If you look up a band structure plot where they have included very deep levels, those are all basically horizontal lines precisely because there is no variation in energy in those deep, core, levels.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent For tightly bound electrons, the orbital model is perfectly reasonable. The band model adds no value in most circumstances.

Comment: Thanks both, is it correct to think of the valance band in ionic/covalent solids as the highest "deep" level?

Comment: @Gotaquestion If you like. The crystal doesn't care what words you use.

Comment: @JohnDoty I have not asserted in any way that the orbital model is otherwise for tightly bound core electrons. I am simply pointing out a mathematical fact that the band model will incorporate them correctly and perfectly, just that those bands will be flat and uninteresting. It is still useful and helpful because having them all in the same mathematical framework allows for completeness relations and other nice theoretical properties, things that, no doubt, you are not at all interested in, and so please stop confusing people with non-answers. Leave theory to theorists.

Comment: The valence and conduction bands, by definition, have a lot of overlap and should not be considered a deep level at all. But yes, it is the highest filled band.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Is it always the case that localized electrons are in flat bands?

Comment: Yes, localised electrons will always appear as flat bands. It should be easy to see why.

Comment: I think I got it now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bands and bonds are models.

```
"All models are wrong but some are useful." -- George Box
```

The simple localized bond model fails even for small molecular rings when there is [aromaticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromaticity). You can, if you like, think of metallic bonding as as similar phenomenon, but on a lattice, not a ring.

If you model the electrons as waves, you may conceive of the ring as tightly confined box for electron waves. In a tightly confined box, you get isolated resonant frequencies. But in a big box, a crystal, you get many closely spaced resonances, a band.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood you correctly. In the conduction band of a metal (where overlapping is significant) there can only be two electrons with the exact same energy in the lattice. In the valance band of a covalent solid (where there is barely any overlap), the number of electrons that have the same exact energy is equal to the 2 multiplied by the number of atoms in the lattice. Is that right?

Comment: @Gotaquestion Each energy level in a band may only be occupied by two electrons. But it's a band of many closely spaced levels (infinitesimal spacing in the limit of an infinite crystal).